# Complex Wireframe to solid for use in Autodesk 2018

Tags: 3d, modeling, autodesk, solidworks, wireframe

I'm working on a project for a piece of coursework which I really need a hand with. I can't figure this out and have tried looking at multiple google searches' and community posts which all seem to be out of date...

This help request is explained in detail in parts 2,3 & 4. If you do not want to view the images, files or additional information, please skip all other sections.

## 1. Quick background about the project

For uni, I have to create a stage design for a festival. The idea behind the design is a Mountain troll leaning on some buildings with LED veins which change colour, lava falling from the mouth and down the sides of the buildings it's leaning on.

## 2. My problem

So, I attempted to design the main features, the head in Autodesk originally, however, could not get it to look how I wanted it to. So I decided to move to a more modelling based program, Zbrush 4R7, which make a great model (head.obj in the files section). It looked exactly how I wanted it to.

So I attempted to export this file to use it within Autodesk inventor, and I could not get anything to convert it into a solid shape. The closest I got was a wire mesh shape which claimed to be converted, however, it wasn't possible to interact with and modify.

### 3. What I have tried

I have attempted the following

1. Autodesk AutoCAD 2018

   - imported obj file & other file types to get error:
2. Autodesk Inventor 2018

   - Attempted to import using inbuilt systems without success
   - Attempted to use Autodesk Mesh Enabler and convert the mesh after importing.
   - Attempted to import using multiple formats
3. MeshMixer

   - Attempted to convert shape, unsuccessfully. (Not completely sure I understand how to use this properly, happy to try this method again if you can give me a guide)

### 4. What I need it to do

I need the file to be converted into a solid so that I can manipulate it within Autodesk software to use within my design.

I have a huge range of software installed on my pc which I can abuse, if you know a way using any of the following, I would appreciate knowing it. However, I do not have the budget to purchase any products to complete this task.

- Autodesk Inventor 2018
- Autodesk AutoCAD 2018
- Autodesk mudbox 2018
- Autodesk Fusion 360
- Sketchup
- Zbrush 4R7
- Meshmixer
- SOLIDWORKS Professional

## 5. Related Files

Director with files: http://jonathanstevens.org/3dCAD/

To save both you and me time, I have uploaded all files to my web host, so that you can view, attempt things. Hopefully this will speed up the process, or at least you will be able to yell at me angerly for doing something stupid in the file...

Direct Links:

- Head.OBJ - http://jonathanstevens.org/3dCAD/head.OBJ
- Head.ZPR - http://jonathanstevens.org/3dCAD/head.ZPR
- Head.mix - http://jonathanstevens.org/3dCAD/head.mix
- Head.stl - http://jonathanstevens.org/3dCAD/head.stl
- Head v2.OBJ - http://jonathanstevens.org/3dCAD/head%20v2.obj

## 6. Additional help - Then converting to threejs?

If you are awesome enough to know the answer to the problem above, a little tip on how to then convert to threejs would be SOOO appreciated! A link to the best guide or something as simple as that would be a perfect Christmas present xD

Thanks for spending time reading this.

Comment: For the last part, getting the file into three.js, I would export to OBJ, FBX, or glTF and load it with one of the [various loaders](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/js/loaders). You _can_ convert to the three.js JSON format using a Blender exporter, but this isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

For SolidWorks you can try converting it to dxf first as suggested [here](https://forum.solidworks.com/message/229516#229516).

Alternatively you can import it into solidworks as a mesh and then use [Surface Wizard](http://help.solidworks.com/2016/english/solidworks/scanto3d/t_running_the_surface_wizard.htm), note that if you don't see ScanTo3D item in tools menu you need to enable ScanTo3D addin in tools -> addins. If you don't have an addin to enable you'll need to run installation wizard and enable ScanTo3D component under Solidworks parent node.